# How to perform a 'grep' search that excludes line starting with "//"and its preceding spaces?

Tags: regex, grep

How to perform a 'grep' search which doesn't display any lines that have the comment marks "//" in the front of the line, but also ignore whitespace in front of the "//" marks?

I attempted `grep your_search_pattern' where_to_look | grep -v '^//`, but it does not ignore lines that have spaces before "//".

Comment: @Cfreak, I added what I tried. I don't know why this question is still put on hold.

Answer (score 4):

```
 grep 'your_search_pattern' where_to_look | grep -v '^//'
```

Comment: This actually didn't work.  am I supposed to put in the ^ symbol a different way other than just pressing SHIFT-6?  Also, you put single quotes around your queries, should they be double quotes?

Comment: I forgot to mention, some of the lines have whitespace betfore the // mark. I need those lines to be ignored as well.

Comment: please see my above comments

Comment: @Veridian, in this case single vs double quotes doesn't matter since there are no special shell characters in the strings.  For grepping I usually prefer  single quotes since, for example, `$` is a special character in grep and the shell.

Answer (score 3):

You might check out the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) for `grep`.

Some things pertaining to your question:

- the `-v` switch will invert your search
- `^` matches the beginning of the line.

You should be able to piece the rest together.

*(edit: or look above.)*

Comment: Please see my comments to the response above. Can you assist?

Comment: You should look into regular expression pattern rules. `*` after a character means "zero or more," and `\s` represents whitespace, so the pattern `"^\s*//"` should match lines beginning with optional whitespace followed by two forward slashes.

Comment: If I pipe the file I'm searching into the command `grep -v "^\s*//"` I get all of the lines that are _not_ beginning with comments. What is happening for you?

Comment: Nope, is the ^ the standard carrot symbol? If so, then yeah it shows all of the lines with the comments at the beginning still, so it isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

Using awk you don't need to use multiple piped commands:

```
 awk '/paatern/ && !/^\/\//' file
```